# How to make Apache copy certain requests to another webserver?

Tags: apache, http, networking, httprequest, traffic

I have a busy web server running apache. Now I am interested in certain request like:

```
http://myserver1/path1/somepage1.html?xxxxxx
http://myserver1/path2/somepage2.html?xxxxxx
```

What I want to do is to duplicate request like this and forward them to another webserver like:

```
http://myserver2/request_statistic/
```

But the original request must be served on myserver1 as they are now. myserver2 is only for research purpose, so I want the duplicated request headers and bodys are just as the original ones.

Can this be done? How?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where would the response go?

You might try looking at mod_security, which has a number of useful features that would be of use... is your goal security/forensics, or performance analysis?

For performance analysis, I've found it more useful in the past to create a more comprehensive logging format that captures things like response-code, response Location header (for tracking redirects), selected request headers, timing information, etc.

If https is not in use, then you might be better served by something driven by packet-capture. I know that Oracle Real User Information (?) (RUI) works using that principle. For more casual diagnostic sessions, I've often gotten away with the following tcpdump:

```
tcpdump -s0 -A -p -nn tcp and port 80
```

That's enough to get the full requests (and responses), it is a little messy, but the data is all there. You can clean it up a bit with a script, such as the following (tcpdump-http-headers-only) -- its not perfect (particularly on a busy server where things get harder to track).

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Pass in the output of 'tcpdump -s0 -A ...' to this and it will
# output only the HTTP request headers and response headers.
#
# Cameron Kerr <cameron.kerr.nz@gmail.com>
# 2013-02-14
#
grep --line-buffered -o \
        -e $'GET .*\r' \
        -e $'POST .*\r' \
        -e $'^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_-]*: .*\r' \
        -e $'HTTP/1.1 .*\r' \
        -e $'^\r$' \
  | sed --unbuffered -e 's,\r$,,'
```

Alternatively, you might like to capture them (perhaps in conjunction with the -W, -C or -G options) for later analysis. This can, depending on the cipher used, also work with https connections if the key is provided (useful for Wireshark)

Comment: I haven't thought through the response problem, maybe drop it at some stage?

We are using the request data to mining user behaviors, and we want to minimize the modification on existing system.